# determining the series solution from given ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given this equation, I'm trying to find the series solution however I'm not sure how to proceed from finding the identity principle to remove $x^-1$ to find the solutions.

$xy'' + (1-x)y' + \lambda y = 0$

Given that:

$y=\sum_{n=0}a_{n}x^{n+a}$ Then differentiating this as $y' =\sum_{n=0}a_{n}(a+n)x^{n+a-1}$ and $y'' =\sum_{n=0}a_{n}(a+n)(a+n-1)x^{a+n-2}$

Then plugging this into the first equation, heres what I've tried:

$x\sum_{n=0}a_{n}(a+n)(a+n-1)x^{a+n-2}+(1-x)\sum_{n=0}a_{n}(a+n)x^{a+n-1}+\lambda \sum_{n=0}a_{n}x^{a+n}=0$

$x^{a}(\sum_{n=0}a_{n}(a+n)(a+n-1)x^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}a_{n}(a+n)x^{n-1}-\sum_{n=0}a_{n}(a+n)x^{n}+\lambda \sum_{n=0}a_{n}x^{n})$

first and second sum we get $k = n-1$ and $n = k+1$ whilst the third and fourth we get $k=n$

$\sum_{k-1}a_{k+1}(a+k+1)(a+k)x^{k}+\sum_{k=-1}a_{k+1}(a+k+1)x^{k}-\sum_{k=0}a_{k}(a+k)x^{k}+\lambda \sum_{k=0}a_{k}x^{k}=0$

Then separating off the k = -1 and k=0 terms we get:

$(a_{0}a(a-1)+a_{0}a)x^{-1}+(-(a_{0}a)+\lambda a_{0})=0$

Where do I go from here? I understand that I must apply the identity principle to find the solutions.

Do i divide the first part by $x^{-1}$ to get rid of $x^{a}$, then rearrange the equation to make it equal to 0?

such as :

$a_{0}a^{2}+(-a_{0}a+a_{o}a)=a_{0}a^{2}=0?$

Comment: Where does $a$ come from? Why not just $y(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$? And where does your $x^{-1}$ even come from? Differentiating a power series should never yield negative exponents.

Comment: I missed out on a step, I have introduced it now. $x^{-1}$ is given when $k = -1$; Hence when separating the equations, when $k = 0$ then $x^{0}=1$

Comment: But you shouldn't get any $k=-1$ terms.

Comment: I was being guided by lecture notes provided by my lecture, where he gets $k = -1$ terms, because of $x^{a+n-1}$, this is given by the differentiation of $y$. To add further, he mentions: "We now use the identity principle to set the coefficient of each power of x to zero.  For the $x^{-1}$ term". Otherwise, mind showing me what you have in mind?

Comment: I'd just insert a generic power series $\sum n a_n x^n$ into the equation. No negative powers will occur when differentiating such a series.

Comment: You are mistaken, its: $x^{a}\sum a_{n}x^{n} = \sum a_{n}x^{n+a}$. Taking the derivative of this: $(\sum a_{n}x^{n+a})'= \sum a_{n}(a+n)x^{n+a-1}$. perhaps you can produce an answer, so I can understand your solution?

Comment: I didn't post an answer because I didn't manage to solve the recurrence relation I obtained. But anyway, as I asked in the firat comment: where does $a$ come from in the first place? It's not needed for a generic power series (in fact, it might break the power series if chosen badly!) There's probably a reason why you're putting it there. What reason?

Comment: I'ts provided in the question set to me: "show  that  the  indicial  equation  is  satisfied  by $a= 0$,  and  find  the recurrence relation satisfied by the coefficients $a_{n}$."

Answer (score 0):

You did everything correct. That $a=0$ means that the solution will be an ordinary power series, but this is an exception for expansions at regular singularities. It would be better if coefficients and exponent had a different letter as variable name. The coefficient equation at the degree $a+n-1$ is thus
$$
(a+n)^2a_n+(λ-a-n+1)a_{n-1}=0.
$$
With $a=0$ this reduces to
$$
a_n=\frac{n-1-λ}{n^2}a_{n-1},~~n\ge 1.
$$
If $λ$ is a positive integer, this recursion will give a finite sequence (only a finite number of non-zero coefficients).